# How to have a textfield scan for all values in an array individually in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am relatively new to swift and programming languages of its kind, and I have really been struggling with having a textfield look for ALL values individually in a string array. So 
here's my code:

```
var greetingArray = ["Hi", "hi", "hello", "Hello", "hey", "Hey", "sup", "Sup", "What's up", "what's up"]
```

Above is the array, and below is the textfield's action.

```
@IBAction func textUltraAction(textout: UITextField) { 
}
```

If the "textout.text" is any one of the greetings in greetingArray (but not all of them collectively), I want to complete the action. For example, if "sup" or "hi" is inputed in the textfield, i want to complete the action. I do not want to manually have to type out:

```
greetinArray[0], greetinArray[1], greetinArray[2], etc...
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can give me!

Comment: Consider `contains`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if contains(greetingArray, yourTextField.text) {
    //Here you got it
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)